# PROC TABULATE: Is there a way to control page breaks when writing to PDF output?

Tags: sas

I've used PROC TABULATE to generate 5 different tables and wrote those to a PDF document with ODS. Each table is on a different page. But the boss wants 3 of the smaller tables on the same page and wants the 2 bigger tables to each be on one page.

Is there a way to control the page breaks with PROC TABULATE to get more than one table on a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use paneling to show multiple tables per page.  See [Paneling ODS output](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/htmlpanel.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find a solution. The HTML paneling is cool but I was looking for PDF. Another set of documents discussed ODS layout and the startpage option for PDF.

A simple solution is to put a "startpage=no" statement in the ODS PDF declaration. This turns off the auto-pagination of starting a new page for each table. Then insert a "ODS PDF startpage=now;" statement when you want to start a new page.

Comment: Interesting.  That sounds like a nice simple solution that I'll have to keep in mind.

Comment: The problem I'm having with the "startpage=no" solution is that table titles don't seem to appear for tables after the first one per page. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I found an answer to my problem; in case anyone encounters the same thing: as startpage=no means only one set of titles is printed on one page, you can use the text= option for including titles between tables or graphs. http://support.sas.com/techsup/notes/v8/8/044.html